# Can I remove each instance of a character that occurs immediately after the concurrence of another character?

Tags: java, regex, string, stringbuilder

```
customer2^sc1^admin1|server1~, customer3^sc1^admin1|server3, server2~, customer1^sc1^admin1|server1, server2, server3~
```

For example, can I remove each `,_` after each instance of `~`? How could I achieve this?

Comment: `str = str.replaceAll("(?<=~),", "");`

Comment: `str = str.replaceAll("~, ", "~");` ; removing `, ` after `~` is the same as replacing `~, ` by `~`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use java String replaceAll fonction :

```
yourString = "customer2^sc1^admin1|server1~, customer3^sc1^admin1|server3, server2~, customer1^sc1^admin1|server1, server2, server3~"
yourString = yourString.replaceAll("~, ", "~")
```

Comment: `replace` is sufficient here - you aren't using regular expressions.